# Calling JS Functions from OnClick with Parameters

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to call a js function from the OnClick within multiple DIVs, it passes a 'Section Name' secOther001, 002, 003 etc...'.

```
<?php
$num=mysql_numrows($result);

$i=0;
while ($i < $num) {

$TaskID=sprintf("%03d",mysql_result($result,$i,"TaskID"));
$secOthersID = "SecOther$TaskID";
echo "
<div class='clTaskSection' onclick='SecOtherVisibility($secOthersID)'>...</div>
<div id='$secOthersID' class='clTaskSection'>content...</div>";

$i++;
}

?>
```

it should then call the js below, providing the relevant section name:

```
<script>
function SecOtherVisibility(divName) {
    if (document.getElementById(divName).style.display = "none") {
      document.getElementById(divName).style.display = "block"
    } else {
      document.getElementById(divName).style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>
```

But I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null`.  Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What's PHP got to do with this?

Comment: Have you considered using jQuery?

Comment: Where is `$secOthersID` defined?

Comment: PHP Pulls records from a MySQL DB to create nested DIVs with the record data.  PHP defines $secOthersID

Comment: Typo error: `==` needed in the `if` ;)

Comment: Updated with additional info... <DIV>s are within an echo"..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More importantly, look at the rendered result:

```
... onclick='SecOtherVisibility(SecOther001)' ...
```

Do you see the problem?

How about now:

```
... onclick='SecOtherVisibility(<?=json_encode($secOthersID)?>)' ...
```

Outputs:

```
... onclick='SecOtherVisibility("SecOther001")' ...
```

I hope that clears things up!

Comment: Now I just get [Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <]

Comment: Updated with additional info... <DIV>s are within an echo"..."

Comment: Then just close the quotes - `'SecOtherVisibility(".json_encode($secOthersID).");'`

Answer (score 1):

The function expects a string as `divName`. You are passing the variable `$secOthersID`, which is undefined. Your HTML needs to be something like:

```
<div class='clTaskSection' id="cats" onclick='SecOtherVisibility("cats")'>Contents of div...</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this doesn't work as it has to pass a dynamic value, will try MiDri's example.

Comment: Sorry. I used the wrong quotation marks. Thanks to @SashaPachev for the fix.

Comment: Note that secOthersID is not undefined as if you check the source it is 'secOther001', 'secOther002' etc...

Comment: @aSystemOverload But that's part of the PHP, which never reaches the user. Could you post a more complete section of you PHP script? Are the `<input />`s generated in a loop?

Comment: Updated with additional info... <DIV>s are within an echo"..."

Answer (score 1):

Change it to this:

```
<div class='clTaskSection' onclick='SecOtherVisibility(<?= $secOthersID ?>)'>...</div>
```

You can't just use PHP variables unless in PHP context.

Comment: Now I just get [Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <]

Comment: Might not have shorthand enabled try:
    <?php echo $secOthersID ?>

instead of 

    <?= $secOthersID ?>

Comment: Ahh I think that's throwing everyone who has answered you off.

Comment: Updated with additional info... <DIV>s are within an echo"..."